# ADB refusing connection intermittently on cucumber tests

Tags: android, ruby, cucumber, adb

I am running Cucumber tests against an Android application. On Cucumber runs I will intermittently get a failed test with the message "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host". The same message can sometimes be seen when running a single scenario but it occurs most often when running dozens of scenarios.

I have tracked this down to what I think is an issue with the Android Debug Bridge (ADB) since the same scenarios will pass on other runs of the same scenarios. I have also tried killing the connection (via 'adb kill-server' command) just prior to the Cucumber run with no success.

I am running these tests against a physical device connected via the USB port.

I know this is a highly specific scenario but has anyone else experienced problems like this with the Android Debug Bridge and, if so, what steps did you take?

Answer (score 0):

One option you could try is setting RESET_BETWEEN_SCENARIOS=1 which would uninstall and reinstall the app before each scenario. Not and ideal fix but I am using this option and I do not see the connection error (have around 70 scenarios).

Answer (score 0):

I usually faced this, when the appium will not take a new session, since the existing one would be in progress.

In that case, you will have to just check on the documentation of running `parallel tests`  https://github.com/saikrishna321/AppiumTestDistribution

In My case, Everytime, I face this error, my script restarts the appium with `killall adb` and `adb start-server`